# AJAX responseText missmatch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "testing.php", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        var returnVal = ajax.responseText;

        if(returnVal == "success"){
            // Redirect
        }else{
            // Inform of failure
        }
    }
}
ajax.send("testing=1");
```

that pairs with the following PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["testing"])){
    $formScore = checkForm($db_conx);
    if($formScore == 10){
        echo "success";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "fail";
        exit();
    }
}
```

And this works just fine. The form score is "10" when it should be, and the value sent back to the AJAX call is, in fact, "success". At least, if I print out the response text:

```
$('.output').html(ajax.responseText);
```

the value in `output` is " success" - WITH the space preceding the word. I cannot select the space with my cursor, but it is there when I view the HTML for the page.

But, no matter what, the line `if(returnVal == "success")` always equates to **false**. I've even tried `if(returnVal == " success")`, but still false.

This is all the code. I've even tried hard-coding `$formScore = 10;` to see if that was the issue. Regardless, for some reason the equality always comes out false.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've tested this 100 different ways, and still the same result.

Comment: You probably have a space or BOM before `<?php ... `

Comment: BOM? And no spaces. Everything is as tight as it can get.

Comment: Worst case you do `if (returnVal.trim() == "success"){` but that's just a hack, better to send the right thing from the server

Comment: Yeah, the `.trim()` thing worked out, but I can't find any spaces anywhere.

Comment: Then look for a Byte Order Mark (BOM, which is invisible btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space somewhere in your PHP file which is causing this issue. Possibly at the start of the file before the `<?php`.

To work around this you could trim the response before you use it in the condition:

```
if (returnVal.trim() == "success") {
```

Or alternatively change your PHP to return JSON with the flag as a property, that way whitespace will not be an issue.

The best solution would obviously be to get rid of the space in your server-side code, however we can't diagnose that problem without seeing your PHP.

Comment: You're right. The `.trim()` did the trick, but there are no spaces anywhere in the code before the `<?php ... ?>` blocks. Any other thoughts? They are back-to-back, and nothing precedes them in the file.

Comment: @Birrel that could be the new line characters.

Comment: @Birrel it could be any whitespace character really, new line, tab etc.

Comment: Bah. Humbug. I've combed through it and still can't find anything. BUT, the `.trim()` does the trick, so I'll just leave it at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `trim` function to remove lading and trailing space.

```
if($.trim(returnVal) == "success")
```

Comment: Yeah, the trim worked. But now I'm trying to find where the space is coming from.